# How to get all results from database and set with the right textview

Tags: android, listview, android-database

Please guys i have a custom listview which has product name(Textivew), expirydateStatus(Textview) and a delete button.Now everything works fine,I have been able   to populate listview with data from database.i have a variable which gets the system date and compare it to the expiry date from the database then set the expirydateStatus textview with either expired or active. its displaying only one date through out.

```
 boolean addData(String username,String expiryDate){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_NAME,username);
    cv.put(EXPIRYDATE,expiryDate);

    Long results = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    if(results== -1)
    {
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}

  public  void showUsers()
{
    data = dbHelper.getAllData();
    int counter = 0;
    ///String expdate;
    //String currentDate;
   // String finDate = null;
    if(data.getCount() == 0)
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Database is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }  else {

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        if(data.moveToFirst())
        {
           do
           {

                 //GETING USER NAME AND SENDING TO LISVIEW
                 list.add(new Persons(data.getString(1)));
                   //expdate = data.getString(2);
              //GETING USER EXPIRY DATE SENDING TO LISVIEW
              //list.add(new Persons(data.getString(2)));
               persons.setExpirydate(data.getString(2));

               //Log.i("yolo","Expiry date is "+expdate);


           }while (data.moveToNext());

           customAdapterPeople = new ListAdapterPeople(this,R.layout.row_data,list);

            listView.setAdapter(customAdapterPeople);

        }

    }
    data.close();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lbAp.png)

at first i used log to see my results as you can see its show one user date for all users 
Note below a the results after i log results what am i doing wrong please

I/namy: User Expirydate is 2018/10/5
I/namy: User Expirydate is 2018/10/5
I/namy: User Expirydate is 2018/10/5
I/namy: User Expirydate is 2018/10/5
I/namy: User Expirydate is 2018/10/5

Comment: Are you getting `Database is empty` ?

Comment: no database works fine.I have successfully populated the custom listview with user names from database.The problem is i get the last user i added date set for all other users

Comment: Oh, Can you show your SQL Code for insertion please.

Comment: @UmangBurman  boolean addData(String username,String expiryDate){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_NAME,username);
        cv.put(EXPIRYDATE,expiryDate);

        Long results = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        if(results== -1)
        {
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }

Comment: Can you please update in your question, It's very uncomfortable here.